# Large JSON data for mobile app : should I use array or object?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

Given JSON data being a 50 000 to 300 000 entries dictionary.

Given I build an hybrid app (HTML5/JS/CSS) on mobile, with potential slow devices.

I get my data as am array, but since my users should constantly interact with the data, for the sake of speed and performance,

should I use, query, edit an `array` such (note: I know the target word="zoo")  :

```
var dict = [
   { "word": "acadia", "fr": ... },
   { "word": "acaria", "fr": ... },
   { ... },
   ...
]
```

but I don't have the index, I just have the value "zoo" to get the `{ "word":"zoo"}` object.

Or should I use, query, edit an `object` such :

```
var dict = {
   "acadia":{ "word": "acadia", "fr":... },
   "acaria":{ "word": "acaria", "fr":... },
   "...":   { ...                        },
   ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but dude, you can't download a huge dictionary like that to my mobile phone. It's just not practical. You'll fill up my memory card, and it'll take hours at normal speeds, even here in NY. You really should consider another solution.

Comment: My current approach is I will provide the 50 000 most frequent item to download for sure. Should just take few minutes. The rest is an other question. But at least, I need to work with the best approach

Comment: So from server send 100 records it will be easy to download

Comment: Ok, forget the API thing. +It will download the data from a file just once when installing the app.

Comment: [Maybe think about using a trie](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=120).

Comment: This take us back to the indexed object `var dict = { "z": {"word":"zoo"},{"word":"zoro"}}` approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Array**

Objects are slower then arrays.

The code to write an object is longer than tho write an array.

when i load much data like that i compress the response as follows:

```
obj={
 info:{en:0,fr:1,es:2,it:3},
 data:[
  ['acadia','... ','...'],
  ['acaria','... ','...'],
 ]
}
//access

var wordNumber=0,lng=obj.info.en;
obj.data[wordNumber][lng];
```

but the it also depends on how you structure/index everything.

so maybe

```
obj{
 'acadia':['fr...','es...','it...'],
 'acaria':['fr...','es...','it...'],
}
// access:
var word='acadia',lng=0;
var word=obj[word]?obj[word][lng]:'word does not eist';
```

is faster as it has direct access...

but no duplicatetes and no unallowed characters. you need to check that.

*not shure if fr is for france word... correct me if i'm wrong. and i edit the code.*

btw .. i loaded a json file of 20mb on ipad1 witout problems... it contained the exif data of 20k images.And it was written vary bad.. you could use `cache.manifest` or `webSQL` to store it permanently... and considering that my json file was written very bad.. the dictionary with 300k entries should be the same size if using arrays.

but for a such big data & if you constantly update you should also be able to use some serverside language and a proper DB where you update only the necessary data.

**EDIT**

data.json

```
{
 info:['en','fr','it'],
 data:[
  ['enword1','frword1','itword1'],
  ['enword2','frword2','itword2'],
  //.....
 ]
}
```

then store everything in a webSQL DB..
and use that.. for offline.

to create a even smaller jsonfile

```
{
 info:['en','fr','it'],
 data:[
  ['enword1,frword1,itword1'],
  ['enword2,frword2,itword2'],
  //.....
 ]
}
```

then use `split(',')` words should not contain `,`

---

**Smaller** so the json file is very small.

```
{
 info:['en','fr','it'],
 data:'enword1,frword1,itword1|enword2,frword2,itword2'
}
```

words should not contain `,` & `|`

```
words=data.split('|'),l=words.length;
while(l--){
 word=words[l].split(',');//en,fr,it
 // insert into webSQL
}
```

but you need to test if the brosser can handle that easy.

you need to find a equilibrium between filesize and how long it takes to inserta all this words..

Comment: We have a server side service under development. But **mobile first** require to provide a solid off line service as well. `fr` stand for French, yes.

Comment: then yeah.. the 2nd code should be the smallest & also the fastest to index.use cache.manifest to store the js file.. or webSQL if not enough space.btw.. example..